# Interior of a connected set is connected

Tags: general-topology

I know interior of connected set in a metric space need not be connected. Simplest example would be to take two tangent closed disk in Euclidean plane.

I am trying to construct a counterexample in $\mathbb{R}$?  I mean I am trying to find a connected set in $\mathbb{R}$ such that interior is not connected.

Thanks for reading, and helping out.

Comment: In $\mathbb{R}$ this is not possible because the connected sets are the intervals.

Comment: The only connected set on this case are intervals.  Does that help?

Answer (score 3):

In $\mathbb{R}$ a set is connected if and only if it is path connected. It follows that the only connected subsets are the intervals $I\subseteq \mathbb{R}$. The interior of a closed interval $[a,b]$ is $(a,b)$, which is again connected. The other cases are the same.

So, every connected subset of $\mathbb{R}$ has connected interior.

Comment: What if the connected set if $\{a\}$? Is the empty set connected? Some people define "connected" as "having exactly one component".

Comment: I suppose that is an edge case : $X=\{a\}$ is connected because the only way to write it as a disjoint union of its subsets is $X=X\sqcup \varnothing$. The empty-set is connected for the same reason : $\varnothing = A\sqcup B $ for $A,B\subseteq \varnothing$ implies $A=B=\varnothing$.